# Why some servers fail when execute "Get-Service"?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, remote-access

I have several servers connected in VPN to my host server. All run windows 7.
I'm running in loop `Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name Spooler` for each server. For some reason some of them return the service successfully and some don't saying `Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Spooler'`. I know for 100% that all of them have `Spooler` service.

Probably something is configured differently on the servers that fail to return the service. Can someone advise what should I check for?

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause is you don't have sufficient privileges to query services on remote machine. Try without specifying the `-Name` argument, eg:

```
get-service -ComputerName TEST-CLIENT
```

Where TEST-CLIENT is your server name. And see if you get a better error message, eg:

```
get-service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'TEST-CLIENT'. This operation might require other privileges.
```

If this turns out to be your issue you can try granting remote logon and/or administrator access to your account on the remote machine. Without more details of your setup I can't give a more exact solution.

Comment: It returns `Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'myserver'. This operation might require other privileges`. All servers were imaged from the same image. So, they should be identical. I entered `\\myserver` in file explorer and it opened `Windows Security` window to enter username and password. Once I provided the username and password it succeeded to enter. But, when I ran `Get-Service...` again I got the same error. Any ideas? What additional details do you need?

Comment: Sounds like you may not have Powershell Remoting set up correctly on the server (for whatever reason). Try on the server: `Enable-PSRemoting` and then `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '*'` (or better than `*` would be your computername.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the privileges issue, I think the next most likely culprit is that your $server variable is not the correct type.

Looking in the help file for Get-Service. We can see that -ComputerName only accepts String values.

```
    PS C:\Temp> Get-Help Get-Service -Parameter Computername

    -ComputerName **<String[]>**
Gets the services running on the specified computers. The default is the local computer.

Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of a remote computer. To specify the local computer, type the computer name, a dot (.), or localhost.

This parameter does not rely on Windows PowerShell remoting. You can use the ComputerName parameter of Get-Service even if your computer is not configured to run remote commands.

Required?                    false
Position?                    named
Default value                None
Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

If you set your $server variable using Get-ADComputer, the variable probably contains the object type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer"

```
    PS C:\Temp> Get-ADComputer -Identity AE-HTPC | Get-Member
       TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer
```

If you grab the object and expand out the contents to String then you will have a variable that Get-Service can understand.

```
    PS C:\Temp> Get-ADComputer -Identity AE-HTPC | Select-Object -
    ExpandProperty Name | Get-Member
       TypeName: System.String
```

...
...

Results Replicated...

```
    *PS C:\Temp> $server = Get-ADComputer -Identity AE-HTPC

    PS C:\Temp> Get-Service -ComputerName $server
    Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'CN=AE-
    HTPC,OU=HTPC,OU=Workstations,OU=All Clients,DC=ae,DC=kingdom,DC=com'.         
    This operation might require other privileges.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Get-Service -ComputerName $server
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

    PS C:\Temp> $server = Get-ADComputer -Identity AE-HTPC | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

    PS C:\Temp> Get-Service -ComputerName $server
    Status   Name               DisplayName                           
    ------   ----               -----------                           
    Stopped  AdobeFlashPlaye... Adobe Flash Player Update Service     
    Stopped  AJRouter           AllJoyn Router Service*
```

I hope this answer isn't too detailed. It's my first one. Let me know if it helps.